# Swift: Use OpenGLES to take a screenshot

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

I know there are samples on how to use Apple's OpenGLES to take full screenshots, but there are no Swift functions that I can use. I can't read Objective-C, and I'm sure other Swift users would also love a function on how to capture the screen using OpenGLES.

I am wanting to use OpenGLES to take a screenshot because the normal code:

```
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.bounds.size)
    let image = renderer.image { ctx in
        view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil)
```

doesn't save a screenshot of the live camera that I am displaying with a UIImageView, it is just all white. Apparently, this can be fixed by saving a screenshot using OpenGLES, but since all functions for it are in Objective-C I can't use them.

Can someone please provide a Swift function to take a screenshot with using OpenGLES? Thank you so much if you do

Comment: Not sure if you know but OpenGLES will be deprecated in iOS 12 https://developer.apple.com/ios/whats-new/ Just as a heads up :)

Comment: @Redssie Ok thanks I didn’t know. The  what alternatives could u suggest for my issue? (Screenshot of the live Camera is all white)?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help you with that since I haven't done anything like that (or with OpenGLES). I just saw the release notes for iOS 12 and I know how painful it is to change code that's been deprecated.